# How to use dynamic vars in VBNET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, dynamic-variables, my.resources

How I can take the text of the button to use it like a resource name?

My try:

```
Public Sub LlamadaButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
   Dim ButtonN As Button = CType(sender, Button)
   Dim ResourceName = ButtonN.Text
   ReadDelimitedText(My.Resources._(ResourceName), ";")     ' The problem: My.Resources._(ResourceName)
   End Sub
```

Error: Identifier expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d17ax2xk%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method.

```
Dim ResourceName = ButtonN.Text
ReadDelimitedText(My.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("_" & ResourceName), ";")
```

Comment: thankyou, i've used ".getobject" instead of ".getstring" and runs good, Any difference?  PS: the resource is a Textfile

Comment: It states in the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.getobject.aspx) that it returns the **"Returns the value of the specified non-string resource."**, but since you are using a Textfile and it is working for you, I guess that is what maters.  Your are welcome and I am glad to be of help.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script runat="server">
Public Sub LlamadaButton(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
  Dim ButtonN As Button = CType(sender, Button)
  Dim ButtonText = ButtonN.Text
  MsgBox(ButtonText)
End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button Bob" />
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this what you mean?, clicking on the button will show the text in a messagebox, try and change the button text and click it again

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your resource file name is `Resource1.resx`, and your string in it is `String1`, you should be able to access it like this:

```
My.Resources.Resource1.String1
```